# Is there a continuous differentiable function with bounded support and polynomial behavior at origin?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find a function $f$ that is continuously differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, i.e. $f \in \mathcal{C}^1((0, \infty))$, that also has bounded support and fulfills $f(x) \sim cx^\alpha$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ where $c \neq 0$ and $\alpha > 0$.

Is there a way to specifically construct such a function? I have tried looking at bump functions and finding $f$ as a convolution of a function with bounded support and a bump function. But that did not yield anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct such a function with polynomials in a piecewise manner:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
cx^{\alpha} & x\in(0,1)\\
c(\alpha+2)x^{3}-c(5\alpha+9)x^{2}+4c(2\alpha+3)x-4c(\alpha+1) & x\in[1,2)\\
0 & x\geq2
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Interesting. How did you come up with the coefficients in this case?

Comment: 4 conditions: the second segment should match the value and derivative of the first segment at $x=1$ and it should match the value and derivative of the third segment at $x=2$

Answer (score 1):

With a product instead of convolution it should work.

Consider the differentiable function
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\chi:\Bbb R & \rightarrow & \Bbb R\\
x & \mapsto & \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & x<-2\\
\exp(\frac{1}{(x+1)^2-1}+1) & x\in [-2,-1]\\
1 & x\in [-1,1]\\
\exp(\frac{1}{(x-1)^2-1}+1) & x\in [1,2]\\
0 & x>2
\end{array}\right.
\end{array}$$

Then $\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R, x \mapsto c x^n \chi(x)$ is differentiable with compact support as product of two differentiable functions, one of which with compact support. Since $\chi$ is constant around zero, the behavior of the product around zero **is** $c x^n$.

Comment: You did not define $\chi$ properly. It is not even continuous.

Comment: Darn it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think scaling the exponentials with $e$ and restricting their support should suffice. Then it works.

Comment: It should. Sorry for this, I quickly looked up some bump functions and might have looked at the wrong picture.